# Can we say that a record in a database is a collection of entity?

Tags: database, entity, record

Today in Technical Aptitude class teacher told me that a record in a database is a collection of entity. But i have doubt. Please tell me that it is true or false.

Comment: It's true. Why should you have doubts on your teacher's knowledge?

Comment: I think it is collection of fields which have some separate value but when we talk about entity it have some properties and behavior.

Comment: And one other point- take an example:a company have many employees ,and these employees are defined as entities(e1,e2,e3....) and all these entities having same attributes than theses attributes are implemented as fields. Thats why i am saying it as a collection of fields.

Comment: But fields **DO HAVE properties**!! i.e. Data Type, Nullabillity, Default Value, AutoIncrement, Primary Key, Unique, ... A row is a collection of **fields**, but a field is an **object** (entity)

Comment: now I hav no doubt. thanks for your perfect answer Frank N. Stein .

Comment: actually at that time teachar was too confused, he was telling unique and primary key both the same thing,,,,these things were creating doubt about his knowledge

Comment: Please, trust your teachers. They are experienced people. Maybe sometimes not inthe right mood to explain something clearly. Feel free to ask them again, they'll try to explain the concepts in other words. Have a good day.

Comment: I made an answer out of my comments, so you can accept it, in order to remove your question from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

Fields are objects, and - as such - do have properties (i.e.: Data Type, Nullabillity, Default Value, AutoIncrement, Primary Key, Unique, ...).

A row is an entity (a collection of fields), but also a field is an entity.

We could define a row a **meta-entity**, since it is an entity of entities.
And so, a table is a a meta-meta-entity, and a db a meta-meta-meta-entity... ;)